# DataGrid does not displaly new items when it's on Page

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Page with a DataGrid and a button that adds a new Item into the DataGrid. When I click the button item does not displayed, but through debugger I can see that it was added into the DataGrid.

I tried to copy a XAML and CodeBehind of the Page into a new Window and it started working, but I need it to work inside the Page.

---

I have a constructor of the page where I define dataGrid columns and `ClearPage()` method that clears the Page on unhiding:

```
        public CreateTablePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var columnPK = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            columnPK.Header = "PK";
            columnPK.Binding = new Binding("PK");
            dgMain.Columns.Add(columnPK);

            var columnName = new DataGridTextColumn();
            columnName.Header = "Name";
            columnName.Binding = new Binding("Name");
            dgMain.Columns.Add(columnName);

            var columnType = new DataGridTextColumn();
            columnType.Header = "Тип";
            columnType.Binding = new Binding("Type");
            dgMain.Columns.Add(columnType);

            var columnUQ = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            columnUQ.Header = "UQ";
            columnUQ.Binding = new Binding("UQ");
            dgMain.Columns.Add(columnUQ);

            var columnNN = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            columnNN.Header = "NN";
            columnNN.Binding = new Binding("NN");
            dgMain.Columns.Add(columnNN);

        }

        public void ClearPage()
        {
            dgMain = new DataGrid();
            tbColumnName.Text = "";
            tbFKName.Text = "";
        }
```

And I have a Click event handler where I add a new Item

```
        private void bAddColumn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddColumn();
        }

        private void AddColumn()
        {
            var data = new DbTableItem { PK = true, Name = "Test", Type = "Int", UQ = false, NN = false };
            dgMain.Items.Add(data);
            //debuger shows that Items was added, but nothing is displayed on datagrid
            //when I run this code inside the Window it does work
        }

        public sealed class DbTableItem
        {
            public bool PK { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public bool UQ { get; set; }
            public bool NN { get; set; }

        }
```

the XAML and CodeBehind is the same for Window and Page, I just changed a constructor name, but when it's Page a new Item does not display in DataGrid and when it's Window everything works properly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How do you display the `Page` itself in the window?

Comment: the `Page` is hosted in a `Frame` that is a child of `Grid` inside MainWindow

Comment: Please post your code including all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was super stupid.

On the first line of the `ClearPage()` method I create a new instance of the `DataGrid` and assign it to the `dgMain` to "clear" it. This action creates a new `DataGrid` that is represented in memory, but not on the `Page`. So thats why I don't see any changes of it.

The proper way to clear it is to call `dgMain.Items.Clear()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to use the ItemSource property of the datagrid and bind it to an ObservableCollection. This way when you execute the add button, just add the new object into the ObservableCollection.